# Problem to cancel a "while" loop in Android

Tags: java, android, while-loop

First of all, sorry for the not-very-descriptive title.

I've got the following code that it's not working properly (or as I'd wanted).

Even though I call "Cancel()", the while goes on...

```
private boolean cancelled;

private synchronized Bitmap renderBitmap(PatchInputStream pis){
              File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+url);

              FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
              byte buf[]=new byte[2000];
              int len;
              while((len=pis.read(buf))>0 && !isCancelled() ){
                  fos.write(buf,0,len);
              }
              fos.close();
              if (isCancelled()){
                cancelled=false;
                return null;
              }

              Bitmap bm = saveBitmapToFile(file);
              return bm;
}

public boolean isCancelled(){
    return cancelled;
}

public void Cancel(){
    cancelled=true;
}
```

What's wrong with this code? Am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, obvious question - are you calling `Cancel()` [upper-case method name. Bad!] from a separate thread?

Comment: Obvious question 2 - if you're calling it from a separate thread, is the method calling `Cancel` using `synchronized` as well?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the `while` loop - are you sure Cancel() is being called on the right object?

Comment: As an alternative to synchronized you could add the volatile keyword to your boolean

Comment: Can you show the code were you are calling cancel?

Comment: Also, you don't need to use isCancelled() inside the class - you can just access the field directly.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using isCancelled().

Comment: Also - marking a function that does some extensive work `synchronized` is also bad form, you could stall another thread for quite some time. It may be necessary, and I can't judge it without seeing all of the code. But if you don't have to make it `synchronized`, then don't.

Comment: Adding the volatile keyword solved a similar problem for me.

Comment: @EboMike 1 - Yes, I call it from the main Thread. 2 - Now I've tried both of them not synchronized.
@Anthony Grist Yes.
@mibollma I've tried that and it's not working.
@James Scriven I call aA.Cancel(); on a click from a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least the code has a concurrency bug which can be solved by making `cancelled` `volatile`. Otherwise the other thread is not guaranteed to see the new value.
*(Apparently this was not the case.)*

Another possibility is that the cancel() method is not called.
*(Apparently this was not the case.)*

Still one more possibility is that the cancel() method is being called on a different object instance. Try adding `System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(this))` to both the cancel() method and the while loop and see if they print the same value.

Comment: The problem could also be in the code which calls cancel(). Or then the read() method blocks indefinitely while waiting for more input. Or the cancel() method is being called on the wrong object. Add a println() statement in the cancel() method and the beginning of the while loop. Is the while loop executed many times even after calling cancel()? Please post a http://sscce.org/

Comment: System.out.println(); Does not output anything.
System.out.println(cancelled); Prints "true" in the cancelled method and false in the while loop.

Yes, the while loop is executed until it finishes its work.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(this)` print in the cancel method and while loop? Assuming that toString() and hashCode() methods are not overridden, that should print the class name and a number which identifies the object instance. If the print output differs, then they are different objects.

Comment: They were different objects!
When I did the Cancel() I was actually doing it to the old object because the new one was still being created. The "renderBitmap" function was part of the constructor and it could take up to 15 seconds.

I've solved it by moving these heavy process outside of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use `volatile` on the cancelled instance variable as suggested by @mibollma. This will assure that no Thread is using a cached version of the variable. If that does not work, you can try the following suggestion:

Your `cancel()` method is probably not being invoked, the Thread with the while loop is not permitting it. Use the [`Thread.yield()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) method.

> Causes the currently executing thread object to temporarily pause and allow other threads to execute.

In your while loop:

```
          while((len=pis.read(buf))>0 && !isCancelled() ){
              fos.write(buf,0,len);
              Thread.yield();
          }
```

Comment: I disagree... i don't think the Android scheduling algorithm is that naive. Instead there is not guarantee that the change in cancel reaches the other thread since it's not synchronized.

Comment: You would think that `write()` is I/O bound and will eventually yield, and assuming that the two threads have the same priority, you would assume that the thread writing the data will get preempted.

Comment: Probably all that is needed is for the cancelled variable to be `volatile`.

Comment: @mibollma Not sure I understand the "reaches the other thread"  It is the same variable being accessed from 2 different threads.  The issue with synchronization here is trying to read it while it is being set.

Comment: @Rob From my understanding the writing thread might cache the boolean until he is forced to synchronize. So the reading thread will read the old value until the writing thread synchronizes its cache.

Comment: @mibollma I think you are on the money, and I reflected it on my answer.

Comment: @RobGoodwin I think it's implied since if another thread was not involved then "who" would be calling cancel?

Comment: It's actually being invoked. I've debugged the code and it actually changes the "cancelled" value.

I've tried your solution and doesn't work either.